# ¿Por que si poseo un formato de codificación determinado aparecen caracteres especiales (Ã± y Ã©)?

Tags: javascript, html, codificación

Si utilizo esta etiqueta en todos mis documentos

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

por que?, algunos partes del codigo salen como:

```
ContraseÃ±a y CÃ©dula: (html) 


Ã¿Estad usted seguro?(javascript alert)
```

y en otros salen con tilde y eñe normal:

```
 Ingrese la contraseña  y la cédula
```

Si utilizo `&LETRAacute;` se acomoda, pero hay documentos donde no lo tengo y tambien muestra los tildes y las eñe

Que puede estar ocurriendo?

Quisiera que saliera la eñe y tambien las tildes, no el `Ã±`

Comment: Que codificación usaste en el editor con que creaste tu código?

Comment: @StefanNolde Especifica mejor a que llamas codificacion jejej, HTML con PHP e inclui librerias jquery y javascript

Comment: Debería especificar mejor a que llamo editor ;) Los textos mal codificados vienen de una base de datos o están dentro de un archivo? Si vienen de una base de datos puedes revisar la configuración de charset de las tablas. Si estan en el archivo, revisa en que formato tu editor guarda los archivos.

Comment: Jjaajajaja lei mal, los de las tablas salen bien con todo y tilde
Los mal codificados son los mensajes javascript.

Tuve que colocar como le responi a JSON, el iso-8859-1 en un encabezado que tengo y el utf-8 en cada archivo y pude corregir los tildes con &acute y &tilde pero los javascript salen con esa A adelante de las preguntas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si trabajas en un sistema con una variedad de tecnologías (php, html, javascript, bbdd, llamadas remotos) te ahorras muchas problemas de si manejas todo en la misma codificación. Eso incluye en el caso que trabajas con ´utf-8`:

- Asegúrate que tu editor guarda todos los archivos en utf-8
- Declara uso de utf-8 en los archivos html
- Declara uso de utf-8 en tablas de BBDD
- Considera transferir datos con XML declarando utf-8 en la cabezera
- Si tomas acceso a servicios de otra codificación, implementa una conversión en la entrada

Cuando ves `Ã±`, eso es la representación en ISO-8859 de una `ñ` codificada en utf-8, si así se te demuestra en una página de utf-8 significa que la fuente del texto fue originalmente utf-8, luego fue por un artefacto interpretado como ISO y al fin reconvertido a utf-8.

Si quieres ayuda en particular como asegurarte de trabajar con utf-8, añade una lista de los artefactos y herramientas que usas a tu pregunta y te pueden llegar respuestas concretas como cambiar la codificación de esta parte de tu sistema a utf-8.

Para encontrar la fuente de los errores tienes que averiguar de donde te vienen estos textos:

- ContraseÃ±a y CÃ©dula: (html)
- Ingrese la contraseña  y la cédula

Si por ejemplo el primer texto es un texto fijo en un archivo html, significa que el archivo esta guardado en utf-8, pero la pagina se muestra con ISO-8859.

Si el segundo texto es texto fijo en tu archivo html, puede ser que codificación y configuración del html esta lo mismo, aun no puedes estar seguro si es ISO-8859 o utf-8.

Para empezar te recomiendo que te aseguras que todos los archivos con textos fijos estén guardados en utf-8, luego ves como se muestran.

Comment: Sobre lo que dices texto fijo, resulta que "Ingrese la contraseña y la cédula" aparece bien en el codigo html algo asi <p>Ingrese la contraseña y la cédula</p>.
Como verifico que esten en utf-8?.
Coloque en el encabezado php el meta como utf-8 y los datos de la base de datos salen con el <?> en las tildes, revise la bbdd y tiene esto: latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: cambie a utf8_spanish_ci Todo el cotejamiento de la base de datos

Comment: El editor es sublime text 3

Comment: Agrega estos datos a tu pregunta. Yo no he trabajado con sublime text, pero va haber usuarios que te pueden decir de la memoria como comprobar la codificación en este editor y como convertirlo en guardar. ;)

Comment: como corrigo entonces para que salgan las tildes teniendo utf8_spanish?

Comment: utf-8 es utf-8, no hay utf-8 spanish, porque ya permite internacionalisación sin discriminar entre regiones (como en ISO-8859). Por eso se prefiere a esta altura. Como lo corriges te expliqué en forma genérica en la respuesta, para explicartelo más concreto tienes que revisar los formatos y dar la información en tu pregunta que esta códificado en que formato.

Comment: creo que se corrigio asi:

encabezado.php: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

cada archivo: <meta charset="UTF-8">

BBDD: utf-8_spanish_ci

Comment: en phpmyadmin salen como 60 tipos de utf-8

Comment: Eso no es la codificación, esso es la collation. Las reglas para ordenamiento, pero eso no tiene impacto a la representación visual ;) En tu encabezado tienes que cambiar `charset=ISO-8859-1` a `charset=utf-8`, luego ves que te sale mal todavía

Comment: yo deje asi esto y funciono: encabezado.php: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> cada archivo: <meta charset="UTF-8"> BBDD: cotejamiento: utf-8_spanish_ci

Por cierto el cambio del cotejamiento afecta los datos? por ejemplo que pase un dato de una tabla con utf-8 a una con latin?

Comment: Si tienes una diferencia ente codificación entre el encabezado y la base de datos, en php puedes usar por ejemplo [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) para recodificar correctamente. Yo en todo caso te recomiendo de refacturar **todo** a utf-8, hace tu código más simple y flexible para i18n.

Comment: hasta ahora el unico que causa problemas es el Á antes del signo de interrogacion en javascript

Comment: Y tienes tu pagina con charset=ISO8859 ahora o con charset=utf-8?

Comment: El encabezado con <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

y en cada pagina ytf-8

Comment: Con la respuesta a otra pregunta que hice parecida a este, tuve que aplicar el cambio a UTF-8 pero en la conexion a la BBDD como me decias, jejeje luego de que estaba todo bien empezo a fallar

Answer (score 3):

puedes probar lo siguiente

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Comment: Esta es la codificacion que uso para Tildes y Ñ's

Comment: esto me salio en las tildes: Ãº 
esto esn las eñes: Ã±

Comment: Tengo esto en un encabezado que incluyo en todos los archivos <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> eso permite que no salga el signo ? en un triangulo donde estan palabras con tildes y eñes, y en cada html uso esto <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando html5 es mejor que uses esta otra etiqueta meta:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice para dar solución luego de leer la buena respuesta de @StefanNolde, fue lo siguiente:

**Me parece que soluciona pero pienso que podría hacerse mas sencillo**

- En mi encabezado PHP utilice: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">`

> Esto me ayudo a que los `<?>` en los acentos por los valores de base de datos salieran asi `éjemploñ`

- En mi BBDD cambie el cotejamiento a `UTF-8_spanish_ci`

> Supongo que ayuda que sea cotejamiento en castellano y no en sueco como lo tenia

- En el sublime text se utiliza `WESTERN`, el cual es una combinacion (algo asi entendi) de codificacion entre `UTF-8` , `UTF-16` y otra mas, colocando por defecto UTF-8 en los archivos.

> No hubo problema con el guardado de los archivos

- Utilice `UNICODE` para generar los caracteres especiales en Javascript

  \u00e1 -> á
  \u00e9 -> é
  \u00ed -> í
  \u00f3 -> ó
  \u00fa -> ú
  \u00c1 -> Á
  \u00c9 -> É
  \u00cd -> Í
  \u00d3 -> Ó
  \u00da -> Ú
  \u00f1 -> ñ
  \u00d1 -> Ñ
  \u00BF -> ¿

> Me permite hacer alerts con preguntas, tildes en las palabras y la letra eñe, `"\u00BFEsta seguro que desea cambiar la contrase\u00f1a?"`

- En HTML/PHP las palabras que estaban en en el documento salen con tildes y caracteres especiales como la ñ, alli no hubo problema en algunos documentos, para los que presentaban ausencia de tilde y de eñe, utilice: `&LETRAacute;` y `&LETRATilde;`.

> Permitio obtener algo asi: Ocurrió y Contraseña aplicando: `Ocurri&oacute;` y `Contrase&ntilde;`

Comment: Si te funciona esta bién, sin embargo si es posible todavía te recomiendo de cambiar **todo** a utf-8, puede ser que tienes que transformar algunos datos en el proceso de refacturación, pero despues tienes un sistema más simple y con menos fuentes de errores y más performante, porque no tienes transformaciones entremedio.

Comment: exacto tienes razon @StefanNolde, lo que no me queda claro es como trasnformarlo jejeje

Comment: Depende donde, una busqueda en google te soluciona eso. para mysql por ejemplo [convertir de ISO8859 a utf-8](http://blogofsysadmins.com/convertir-base-de-datos-latin1-a-utf-8-en-mysql), para php [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-convert-encoding.php), para editores normalmente _guardar como_... Eso es un tema para preguntas concretas.